# Does this summary make sense?

Tags: magic, science-fiction, alternate-worlds, worldbuilding-process, alternate-reality

So I'm writing a story where two parallel earths end up fusing together and are becoming one and through some sort of "magic" they don't end up destroyed. So let's say that on the one earth its intelligent inhabitants know that this would occur and have been subtly seeding the other earth for thousands of years so that their species would survive. Now both earths are nearly identical except that one is 20% larger and is 65% water, 20% land and 15% ice, while the other earth is similar to ours. Where there are cities on earth there is nothing on the other and vice versa. Continents would have their land mass increased while nearly all oceans, lakes, rivers and seas dramatically increase in size and depth.

As a commenter said excess land masses are converted into either fuel for the planet core or "energy" that would be used to cool the planet as well as repair any damage to the ozone. Now in this verse that I'm trying create magic is a universal force that is constantly growing and is like an evolutionary medium that alters nearly all living organisms to the point that they can tap into its power. Amalgamation is an event that happens in this verse nearly every ten thousand years and any world that is caught in the middle of this event is enveloped in a blinding light that lasts for hours while its fusion occurs.

Inhabitants of either world are seemingly frozen in place while this happens. I can't really form a question for this, but I would simply like a review. I like to think that this is a reality and world fusion, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: What do you mean by amalgamation and fusing of worlds? Like the two planets get "smashed" together?

Comment: Why do you assume there is one clear answer to this question? Do you think only one obvious thing could happen and just don't quite know what that thing is?

Comment: Oh, btw, I assume that things like gravity, atmospheric pressure, climate, geology, tectonics, the fact that alien life will have a different biochemistry, the orbit around the primary source of energy and so on are of minor importance because "magic"? I think it makes sense given the premise, but it would be worth pointing out imo - or else the answer is as always: Everyone dies. I read your first sentence as that they just don't die in the process. Talking about the result here

Comment: What does the fused world look like? Could I still recognize old world landmasses? Or would continents merge into new landmasses? I think more details on the before and after would help  narrow down the implications.

Comment: Reading this, it feels like you are looking at a world merging with magic and nothing really to do with planets merging. I don't even see a question in your OP.

Comment: Sorry, but the Stack Exchange question and answers format requires a question to which we can provide an answer. If you can't think of a question, that's probably a sign that you are trying to do too much at once. Take a page out of the *Getting Things Done* manual and decide what you need to do next to move yourself closer to your ultimate goal (whatever that may be) and formulate that as a question, then either (a) figure out the answer to that yourself, or (b) if you fail in doing (a), ask on an appropriate Stack Exchange site *and show what you have tried*.

Answer (score 2):

That twenty percent larger is a worry. The smaller Earth could end up inside the bigger one. Also, if they truly amalgamate their combined mass will raise the surface gravity of the new Earth.

However, let's the amalgamation magic works, well, its magic and both Earths are shuffled and dealt to form a new combined world. For the sake of convenience the excess mass has been converted into energy to power the process of conversion into one world.

The inhabitants of what is becoming the one world will see cities popping up where there no cities before. Coastlines will change as their features are combined to make the coastlines. People will suddenly have new neighbours. Wild animals will find their habitats suddenly in the middle of cities.

If there are only intelligent inhabitants on one Earth, and presumably, not on the other then the adaptation will be fairly straight forward. They will warn everyone when it's going to happen. Wait for the landscape to stop changing and just get on with their new world. Cartographers and map makers will have a field day. It is probable some features will be lost in the transformation. Stands to reason really. We can't have everything.

If both former Earths will be inhabited, then the inhabitants of the Earth where they know this is going to happen will have the drop on the inhabitants of unaware Earth. But there could be circumstances the people of one Earth change sides with people of the other Earth because this new Earth is more suitable for than under the old regime. This could be like an invasion with a few rebellions thrown in for good measure.

Obviously the Earth that has known this is going to happen for thousand of years in advance will have the advantage to take over the inhabitants of the other Earth once the amalgamation occurs. A magical invasion that turns into instant occupation.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds very much like asking us to write the story for you, and may be closed for that reason. Some points to consider:

- Who is aware of what happens and when? Magic is a wild card in this regard, it could make both worlds accustomed to *weird stuff*. If they are used to magical plane travel, then magical world-fusing is not much of a stretch.
- Modern-style nations insist on sovereignty over their territory. There is no empty and unclaimed land, only intensively used land and *less intensively* used land -- grazing, lumber, etc. A new city where the national park used to be will upset people.
- Low-tech cities need lots and lots of surrounding villages. Will they come as well?

Comment: Oh no I didn't mean for it to sound like I wanted you guys to write the story for me. I was just curious about what the science behind the fusion of worlds in reality.